# large image when clicking - flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an algorithm working, and I need to click on the image to show it on the entire screen, I have not succeeded, I send all the code, add a comment "// THIS IS THE IMAGE I NEED TO LOOK BIG WHEN I CLICK" which is the image that I want to make it look large when I click it, I have tried in several ways but I have not been able to solve it, and the only thing I am missing is this functionality.

```js
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:tienda/models/productos_model.dart';
import 'package:tienda/pages/otra_pagina.dart';
import 'package:tienda/pages/crear_productos.dart';
import 'package:tienda/pages/pedido_lista.dart';
import 'package:tienda/services/firebase_services.dart';
import 'package:tienda/widgets/header.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        //primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
        primaryColor: Colors.yellow[800],
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'RETO SAN JOSE CHAPARRAL'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ProductosModel> _productosModel = List<ProductosModel>();

  List<ProductosModel> _listaCarro = [];

  FirebaseService db = new FirebaseService();

  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> productSub;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _productosModel = new List();

    productSub?.cancel();
    productSub = db.getProductList().listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      final List<ProductosModel> products = snapshot.documents
          .map((documentSnapshot) =>
              ProductosModel.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data))
          .toList();

      setState(() {
        this._productosModel = products;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    productSub?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, top: 8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.shopping_cart,
                      size: 38,
                    ),
                    if (_listaCarro.length > 0)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 8.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text(
                            _listaCarro.length.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  if (_listaCarro.isNotEmpty)
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Cart(_listaCarro),
                      ),
                    );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        drawer: Container(
          width: 170.0,
          child: Drawer(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
              //color: Colors.black, //color de menu principal
              color: Colors.yellow[800],
              child: new ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    child: new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountName: new Text(''),
                      accountEmail: new Text(''),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: AssetImage('assets/images/food1x.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                 
                  new Divider(),
                  new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(
                      'productos',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    trailing: new Icon(
                      Icons.fastfood,
                      size: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onTap: () =>
                        Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => CrearProductos(),
                    )),
                  ),
                  
                  new Divider(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    WaveClip(),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 48),
                        height: 170,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _productosModel.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 300,
                                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                                  child: Card(
                                    elevation: 7.0,
                                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                                    child: AspectRatio(
                                      aspectRatio: 1,
                                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                          imageUrl:
                                              '${_productosModel[index].image}' +
                                                  '?alt=media',
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          placeholder: (_, __) {
                                            return Center(
                                                child:
                                                    CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                                              radius: 15,
                                            ));
                                          }),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
                Container(height: 3.0, color: Colors.grey),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5.0,
                ),
                Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemCount: _productosModel.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final String imagen = _productosModel[index].image;
                        var item = _productosModel[index];
                        return Card(
                            elevation: 4.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              fit: StackFit.loose,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: CachedNetworkImage(

// THIS IS THE IMAGE I NEED TO LOOK BIG WHEN I CLICK
                                          imageUrl:
                                              '${_productosModel[index].image}' +
                                                  '?alt=media',
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          placeholder: (_, __) {
                                            return Center(
                                                child:
                                                    CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                                              radius: 15,
                                            ));
                                          }),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${_productosModel[index].name}',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 25,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          '${_productosModel[index].price.toString()}COP',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 20.0,
                                              color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: 8.0,
                                            bottom: 8.0,
                                          ),
                                          child: Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                            child: GestureDetector(
                                              child: (!_listaCarro
                                                      .contains(item))
                                                  ? Icon(
                                                      Icons.shopping_cart,
                                                      color: Colors.yellow[800],
                                                      size: 38,
                                                    )
                                                  : Icon(
                                                      Icons.shopping_cart,
                                                      color: Colors.red,
                                                      size: 38,
                                                    ),
                                              onTap: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  if (!_listaCarro
                                                      .contains(item))
                                                    _listaCarro.add(item);
                                                  else
                                                    _listaCarro.remove(item);
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          )),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: where is image?

Comment: the image is uploaded directly from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to show the larger image on the same screen using the dialog below.

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () => showDialog(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                title: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      '${_productosModel[index].image}' +
                                              '?alt=media',
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          context: context),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        child: Image.network(
          BaseUrl.host + posts!.imageUrl!,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new page, wrap the image widget in a `InkWell` widget, and when tapped navigate to the new page showing the image.

EDIT:

Your widget image would become:

```
    // THIS IS THE IMAGE I NEED TO LOOK BIG WHEN I CLICK
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

And then you create a new stateless widget which it builds a:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? url;

  ImageScreen({
    Key? key,
    @required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${this.url}',
          // Ajust the image changing the box fit attributte
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After that when you click the app navigates to a new screen rendering only the image. You can add a back button later.

Comment: And how would it be the truth, I have not been able to do it, I have tried AnimatedContainer and Hero but I have not been able to do it

Comment: I've edited the answer, try now.

Comment: I tried to add the code that you uploaded, but I could not add it to my code, could you help me?

Comment: Why can't you add the code?

Comment: I already mounted the code, but I have not been able to put the "Text" since I do not add them Text (
                                      '$ {_ productsModel [index] .name}',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle (fontSize: 20.0),
                                    )

Comment: In the code I do not add the Text fields, nor the "ontap list cart" in the main and I have not been able to add them as they were in the original file, it is the only thing I am missing.

Comment: This is the code that I have but I am missing what I comment, I will ask you if you can help me : https://github.com/Giovannychvz/flutter

Comment: the algorithm has a problem, when I run it from the emulator it works but if I generate the apk and enter from a cell phone when clicking on the image I have a gray background